# Calling a method within a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to create a javascript object that can call other methods within itself.  However, I'm running into a weird problem that I just can't seem to figure out.

I have the following code

```
myObjectDef = function() {
    this.init = function() {
        //do some stuff
        this.doSecondInit();
    }
    this.doSecondInit = function() {
        //do some more stuff
    }
}

myObject = new myObjectDef();
myObject.init();
```

I am getting an error that states "Message: Object doesn't support this property or method".  And it ends at this.doSecondInit();.  I can't quite figure out why it's doing this.  My code runs great up to the call to the second method.  How do I make this work?

Comment: Your code looks OK and works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vdVE8/ - maybe you'll need to show the missing bits.

Answer (score 3):

There's an extra set of parenthesis here:

```
this.doSecondInit() = function() {
```

You can't assign to the result of a function call, let alone to the result of a function that doesn't even exist.

After your edit, your thing seems to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/nabVN/

You sure you didn't have the same typo in your actual code? Better start getting used to not putting that `()` after every function call, which is probably a bad habit carried over from languages where functions aren't values.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to need to look at my code more carefully. It's definitely not working for me and I definitely don't have the first set of parenthesis. I'm sure there's something else that I'm overlooking at this point.